# Please help...USB device exceeds power limits

Tags: windows-7, usb, power, window

How can I solve this ?

> Error: Power Surge On Hub Port: A USB device has exceeded the power
>   limits of its hub port

Yesterday I faced this problem but it solved when system get restarted. But today it happen again.

I go to Window's Device Manager and find the USB 'root hubs' in there. I have unplugged a couple devices but it still not solved.

[image]

Comment: Please add more details! Your USB device could be a electric car for all that I know.

Comment: @RookieTEC9 thanks for your response..please let me know what details  you want to know

Comment: The manufacter of the device, the model, the usb type (3.0 2.0 1.1) If this error happens in safe mode, if this error happens on other computers. (It's okay if you can't find (catch) them all.)

Comment: I just restarted my system and it can connect to usb now...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Power on of your devices used too much power. Before USB 3.1 there are low limits in power